# The binary in php, why is 63 bits?

Tags: php, binary

The system and PHP version I am using:

- OS: Centos 7 x86_64
- PHP: PHP 7.2

url: http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php

Code:

```
<?php

$a = PHP_INT_SIZE;
$b = PHP_INT_MAX;
$c = PHP_INT_MIN;

echo "The value of \$a: ", $a . "\n";
echo "The value of \$b: ", $b . "\n";
echo "The value of \$c: ", $c . "\n\n";

echo "The binary of \$b: " . decbin($b) . "\n";
echo "The binary of \$c: " . decbin($c) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
The value of $a: 8
The value of $b: 9223372036854775807
The value of $c: -9223372036854775808

The binary of $b: 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
The binary of $c: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The question:

- The binary number of the minimum is 64
- **The binary number of the maximum is 63, why?**

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the leftmost bit in `$b` is 0 and it doesn't get printed.

Try to print `decbin($a)` (since `$a` is 8) to see that it won't print as 64 bits, just 4.

If you want to show the leftmost 0s, use `sprintf` to format the string, as in

```
echo "The binary of \$b: " . sprintf("%064b", decbin($b)) . "\n";
```

Substitute `64` in the format string with however many bits you want to show.

Comment: Also there's a 0 because of two's complement representation.

Comment: `The binary of $a: 1000`. I understand. Thank you for your help.